# Why Laravel does not return an item from a collection

Tags: php, laravel

I have nested `todos`. Every `todo` `hasMany` todo. I try to get all todos on the same level with [staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list](https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-adjacency-list)

I have a collection of todos.

```
[
    [{
        "id": 30000000,
        "todo_number": 1,
        "order": 1,
        "company_id": 1,
        "todoable_id": 20000000,
        "todoable_type": "issue",
        "title": "1. Todo",
        "children_and_self": [{
            "id": 30000000,
            "todo_number": 1,
            "order": 1,
            "company_id": 1,
            "todoable_id": 20000000,
            "todoable_type": "issue",
            "title": "1. Todo"
        }, {
            "id": 30000001,
            "todo_number": 1,
            "order": 1,
            "company_id": 1,
            "todoable_id": 30000000,
            "todoable_type": "todo",
            "title": "2. Todo"

        }]
    }, {
        "id": 30000003,
        "todo_number": 2,
        "order": 2,
        "company_id": 1,
        "todoable_id": 20000000,
        "todoable_type": "issue",
        "title": "4. Todo",

        "closer": null,
        "todos": [],
        "children_and_self": [{
            "id": 30000003,
            "todo_number": 2,
            "order": 2,
            "company_id": 1,
            "todoable_id": 20000000,
            "todoable_type": "issue",
            "title": "4. Todo"

        }]
    }]
]
```

`return $allTodos[0][0];` shows the following result:

```
{
    "id": 30000000,
    "todo_number": 1,
    "order": 1,
    "company_id": 1,
    "todoable_id": 20000000,
    "todoable_type": "issue",
    "title": "1. Todo",
    
    "children_and_self": [
        {
            "id": 30000000,
            "todo_number": 1,
            "order": 1,
            "company_id": 1,
            "todoable_id": 20000000,
            "todoable_type": "issue",
            "title": "1. Todo",
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 30000001,
            "todo_number": 1,
            "order": 1,
            "company_id": 1,
            "todoable_id": 30000000,
            "todoable_type": "todo",
            "title": "2. Todo",
        }
    ]
}
```

`return $allTodos[0][0]->id;` shows `30000000` as expected. Till here everything works well.

But if I try to `return $allTodos[0][0]->children_and_self;` it shows nothing.

If I try to `return var_dump($allTodos[0][0]->children_and_self);` it shows `NULL`

Why `children_and_self` are NULL? What I'm missing?

Comment: Did you tried with camel case like `var_dump($allTodos[0][0]->childrenAndSelf)`?

Comment: @mare96 Thanks. That's the solution. I have to use `childrenAndSelf` and not `children_and_self`. I copied it from the json string what's wrong....

Comment: Ok. I 'll put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON response provides snake case results, but Laravel relations are written as camel case.

So as I mentioned in the comment you will need something like this:

```
var_dump($allTodos[0][0]->childrenAndSelf)
```